# How to read formal definition of a language.

Tags: regular-language

I need to give nondeterministic finite automata for the following language:
$$
L = \{w \in \{a, b\}^∗ \mid w \in ba^*a \cup ((a \cup bb)^*ab^*)\}
$$
The * above are Kleene Stars

I'm having trouble reading this, I think its:

Language $L$ is a set of strings, such that each string $w$ is of the form: Zero or more $ba$, then $a$, then zero or more $abb$, then zero or more $ab$.

Is this right, if not where have I gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't put in enough parentheses for an unambiguous reading. Do you really mean $ba^*$, or do you mean $(ba)^*$? They are two different things. The first includes $baa$ but not $baba$, the second, the opposite.

Comment: The question is given as ba∗, with no parentheses

Comment: In that case, I think it must mean $\{\,b,ba,baa,baaa,\dots\,\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring the $\cup$s, which I gather means "or". Plus, I think you're interpreting the $^*$s incorrectly.

If $w \in L$, then $w$ may be of the form $ba^*a$, or it may be of the form $(a \cup bb)^*ab^*$. The former is $b$ followed by one or more $a$s. Otherwise, it is zero or more instances of $a$ or $bb$ repeated (e.g. $aaabbabbbbbba$), followed by another $a$, then by zero or more $b$s.

Comment: My understanding of the * was its the set of all strings of a given set, combined and concatenated in any order. So with set K = {cat, dog}, then K* = { Ɛ, cat, dog, catcat, catdog, dogdog, catcatcat, catcatdog, etc }. And the ∪ is the union of the sets, so (a ∪ bb )* would be any combination of the set {a, bb}? EG {  Ɛ, a, bb, abb, abbbb, aabb, etc }. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, any combination of $a$ and $bb$, but not necessarily with all the $a$ preceding all the $b$, e.g., $bba$ is in it, as well as $bbaaabbbbabb$ and so on.